# Not extending the application template emberjs

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

IS there any way for me not to extend the application template in Emberjs? As in I have one route that the url needs to be `/questions` for SEO purposes but it has a completely different design than all the other pages. So I don't want it to inherit the application template. Is this possible?

Comment: You can just not put anything in the application template, and put the rest of your routes one level deeper under something like the base route or something.

Comment: @Kingpin2k yes but that would affect the url. it would end up being `/base-route/questions` not just `/questions`

Comment: I was saying use the base route for everything else, that way whatever you had in the application template that you want to show up for everything else would be done there, but not done when you are visiting `/questions`

Comment: @ThreeAccents not correct, if `questions` is defined as a resource.

Comment: I would go with @Kingpin2k's suggestion and simply set `{ path: '/', resetNamespace: true }` on the base route.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options I can think of. The first is that proposed in a comment: create separate top-level routes for `questions` and everything else:

```
// templates/application.js
{{outlet}}

// templates/questions.js
{{! whatever you want for the questions template }}

// templates/base.js
{{! base template stuff, headers, nav bars, content, etc. }}

// router.js
Router.map({
    this.route('questions');
    this.resource('base', function() {
        this.route('base1');
        ....
    });
});
```

The comment that this will result in routes of the form `/base/base1` is not correct. By using `this.resource`, the routes will be of the form `/base1`.

#### Using outlets

There is another approach that may or not meet your needs. It involves putting a custom outlet in the application template, that may be filled in by subroutes. Then define a superclass for "regular routes" which define a `renderTemplate` which renders the header matter into that outlet.

```
// templates/application.js
{{outlet name='header'}}
{{outlet name='main'}}

// mixins/normal-route.js
renderTemplate() {
    this.render('header', {
        outlet: 'header'
    });
}

// router.js
Router.map({
    this.route('questions');
    this.route('base1');
});

// pods/base1/route.js
export default NormalRoute.extend({...
```

This has the benefit of allowing the application template to be more "readable" and semantic, in that it explicitly shows that it is composed of a (possible) header portion, filled in some other components, and a "main" portion.